# Xubuntu 20.04 - Not all RAM is being registered?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, ram

I have 16gb (2x8gb) of Kingston DDR4 2666mhz installed but only 14gb is being detected. (see screenshot below)
[Screenshot of memory info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNIFw.png)

I have an AMD cpu (Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx) - From my understanding, some of my ram is being allocated to run the mobile graphics.

Question 1: Why is only 14gb being detected out of 16gb? (how do I "fix" this)

Question 2: Can I control how much memory is allocated to the mobile graphics?

Comment: Your BIOS or drivers may be reserving a portion fo the RAM as you said for the mobile graphics.  I believe there are BIOS settings to control how much RAM the system uses, from a quick Google the defaults seem to hover from 2 to 8 GB of RAM are pre-reserved for the GPU's memory.  Start by checking your BIOS settings for the GPU?

Comment: Assuming that your video card built into the motherboard. Does your BIOS have anything to say about shared memory settings? This is the first place I'd look for shared memory settings. What is your motherboard make and model?

Comment: The motherboard is by "PK" and the model is "Sleepy_PK" version 1.03

Comment: Maybe just a matter of units? KiB is different than GB.